# What could be the reason 400 error are not being logged in IIS logs?

Tags: valence

I tried getting the IIS logs as per `GMT` (when the call was made) and also the client time zone plus collected the logs for a day before, including and after the day the call was made.

Now I get `200 and 404 error codes`, I do not get `400 error codes` in the logs (or those that I get don't match the user's time stamp of the call)

Are all 400 error codes always logged and what could be the reason they are not showing in the IIS logs?

Is there anything specific we should be keeping in mind when collecting the logs/ queries.

*Note:*  when collecting the IIS logs, I seemed to have gotten some errors regarding file creation etc, could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Check your request logs. Sometimes they don't go in the error log depending on your configuration.